# How can I detect when the value in input text is changed by a script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input text that I need detect when the text (value) change.
The value can be changed in two ways:

1. Allow to the user write in it.
2. The user click a button, runs a jQuery event and fill it with the
   result.

For the item 1 I solved using `keyup` but for the item 2 I have no idea how can I detect when the text is changed.
I try `change()` but does not work.

Comment: Why not just call the extra code after you populate the input?  You can use `$("#id").trigger("keyup");`

Comment: He's probably using some library/widget...

Comment: Can you be more specific, what kind of (jQuery) event does script respond to and whether the _result_ is created and populated synchronously?

Comment: Nice, four answers, each suggesting a completely different solution :). Wondering which one will work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.trigger()` inside your function where you fill the input.

```
$("#idOfButton").click(function() {
    //do some stuff
    //fill input
    $("#edit").val("new stuff!").triggerHandler("keyup"); //<--Trigger keyup event
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8fCa/1

Comment: would `triggerHandler` not work better, as you dont want the element to know about the function call? http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/

Answer (score 0):

Add event handler on `change()` for item2 and in item1 keyup handler, trigger item2 `change()` event. Simple like that...

Answer (score 0):

"runs a jQuery event and fill it with the result."

you can call another function from your jquery event.

```
$('sel').click(function(){
textedited();  // call your new function. 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interval that checks whether the value of the input field has changed in every occasion (user input or button click) :

```
var oldValue = $('#field').val();
var newValue = oldValue;

var checkInputFieldInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
    newValue = $('#field').val();
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        // VALUE CHANGED, DO STUFF
        oldValue = newValue;
    }
}, 100);
```

Note the the "100" is the interval period in ms. You can find more information about the setInterval() method on this page http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do...

```
$('.name').on('keyup', function(){
  /* I'll run when the button is clicked or there's a keyup event. */
})

$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('.name').val('Bill').trigger('keyup');
})
```

Here's a quick demo: http://jsbin.com/uteceb/1/edit